# How do I set DynamoDB requestTimeout using the Go SDK for the default retryer?

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

I know that I can use a context to set the overall query timeout. However, I understand that the DynamoDB client will perform up to 3 retries by default. Is it possible to set the timeout for each of these retries?

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, queryTimeout)
defer cancel()
resp, err := ddbClient.QueryWithContext(ctx, params)
if err != nil {
    return nil, nil, err
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an example of how to do this in the AWS docs here: [Creating a Custom HTTP Client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/custom-http.html).